# Git is not recognized in pycharm

Tags: windows, git, pycharm

I am trying to pull a github repository from bitbucket using pyCharm.

I added the path to my git executable under version control / Git and installed the bitbucket plugin. If I test both it says the test are running fine.

However when I open the terminal now and try to pull a rep like this:

```
 git pull https://marcvanderpeet1983@bitbucket.org/marcvanderpeet1983/betfair_predictions.git
```

I get the following error:

```
 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I had to close ALL of my PyCharm windows and then reopen the project for the updated system path to take effect in the PyCharm terminal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The terminal has nothing to do with those options you have set. The terminal just forwards your commands to the operation system, in your case Windows. You have to add the path to `git.exe` in your `PATH` environment variable, log out and log back into windows to be able to use git from `cmd.exe` or the terminal you are trying to use.

The setting in PyCharm is just for the Git integration, so that PyCharm can use Git. So if you use the PyCharm GUI and menues to use Git, then the setting is used and works. And I guess with the BitBucket plugin you get additional GUI options for cloning, pull-requests and so on, but I don't konw as I don't use the BitBucket.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I changed my path variable with C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe but I still get the same error. Any thoughts on where to look further?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`, not `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`

Answer (score 1):

While integrating PyCharm Community with my GitHub account, I found that following these two steps worked for me (on Windows).

1. **Download** Git separately from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads)
2. **Changing Paths**: Type `Environment Variable` in the start menu -> Select `Environment Variable` at the bottom -> Under System Variables Double-click `Path` -> In the new popped window click `New` -> Add `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` & `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\` at the bottom of the list
3. **Restart system** after closing all running apps  > reopen PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this, Git suddenly stopped working and not recognized in PyCharm, I fixed this issue by in PyCharm:
go to file > sitting > Plugins
search for Git and GitHub and check them
restart PyCharm

Git will work and be recognized again.

Thanks