# PyCharm 'git' is not recognized

Tags: git, pycharm

```
git clone https://github.com/pistocop/subreddit-comments-dl.git
```

in PyCharm, gives this error:

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file

I have activated the virtual environment in PyCharm.
[image]

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Perhaps you need to install git first from https://git-scm.com ? Or it is that your cmd isn't picking up the git executable, check the path variable?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Git is installed in PyCharm! I also added the 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\' and 'C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\' to the environment variables but still the same error!

Comment: What if you try clone this repository as a new PyCharm project? I.e. "New project from VCS", see this post from JetBrains for more: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/set-up-a-git-repository.html

Comment: In the setting, search for `git` and you see the git tab: there you can select where the git program is located

Comment: Did you restart PyCharm after changing the `%PATH%`? (as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74989525/6309))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I restarted the PyCharm. The problem was fixed; it was because git was not installed properly on PyCharm however it was showing activated in the git menu of PyCharm.